# Android: send data to website and receive reply

Tags: android, forms, http

I am working on an lotery app. The hit is to send the coupon number to the lotery server and receive the result (winner price or not). The web ( http://www.telekino.com.ar/ ) has a simple form with three values: emision,cupon,algo

This is the form:

[image]

After fill the form, the web reply  the results

I am lost, what is the best way to duplicate this? . Send the form and receive the results.

Suggestion? tutorials?

Form

```
orm action="/cupones/controlar" id="control_frm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" /></div>              <label for="sorteo">Sorteo</label>
            <select name="data[Cupon][emision]" id="sorteo" class="basic-tooltip"><label for="carton">Número de Cartón</label>
            <input name="data[Cupon][cupon]" type="text" id="carton" value="número" title="Ingrese el número SIN puntos." class="basic-tooltip" />              <label for="algoritmo">Algoritmo</label>
            <input name="data[Cupon][algo]" type="text" id="algoritmo" value="últimos 2 números" maxlength="2" />               <img id="algorithm-help" src="/img/algoritmo.png" alt="últimos 2 números" width="135" />
            <button type="submit" id="control_button">Controlá tu cartón</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Use webservice and for tutorial use google, there are many examples

Comment: Look into the source of that html page. Look for the <form> involved. Add the code of that form to your post. (not in a comment!).

Comment: 'three values(draw number, coupon number, coupon algorith). '. No. They are named different.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Asp.Net Web API for server-side if you prefer Asp.Net (C#, VB.Net)

Comment: ???? OP has no influence on sever of course. He has to use the action described in that form.

Comment: @greenapps: That form is just another client type (web browser), I think he only asks for the way to communicate between android client and remote application server.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and probably best way used in android to communicate with web service is by using **Volley Library** and **PHP, MySql** web service 
[See this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Comment: Sorry but OP cannot influence the server. Or if it uses php. He has to take the server for granted.

Comment: I just send the request to the web page and receive the result (winner price, or not). My intention is to create a Layout with EditTexts , convert to Strings and send this data to the page. I am confused on the way to get this. I am cannot influence the server, just send the data and wait the response.

Comment: Unless the website or the server has given you the access to or APIs to do that you can do that.