# send form and receive response android

Tags: android, http

The idea is duplicate on android this web
http://www.telekino.com.ar/
In the site there is a form to check if your lottery ticket won
[image]

I am confused on how do it. I tried at this way

my layout has three EditText for each one of the form data to be sent (emision,cupon,algoritmo), to be similar to the web, and a button to send the values. 
This is my class

```
 public class Control extends Activity {

private EditText Numerocarton;
private EditText Algoritmo;
private EditText Emision;
public static String emision, cupon, algo;
public TextView resultadocarton;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.control);

    Emision = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emsion);
    Numerocarton = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numerocarton);
    Algoritmo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.algoritmo);


    emision= Emision.getText().toString();
    cupon=  Numerocarton.getText().toString();
    algo=  Algoritmo.getText().toString();




    Button resultados= (Button) findViewById(R.id.controlcartonbut);
    resultados.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        new Title().execute();
        }

    });



    resultadocarton =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultadocarton);

}

// Title AsyncTask
private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String responseString;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post=new HttpPost("http://www.telekino.com.ar/");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emision", emision));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cupon", cupon));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("algo", algo));

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
            resultadocarton.setText(responseString);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("exvcx", "error getting data" + e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        resultadocarton.setText(responseString);
    }


}
```

}

I dont receive results,and mean there is no change on the EditText. Suggestions? maybe other way to create the clon

Comment: Why did you remove your other post? Why not answering the questions there? I was trying to help you. You did not react. Why? And now you continue if nothing has happens.

Comment: The other post still there.never was closed o removed. I considered too confused if I add this code in the other post.

Comment: Then give a link as i cant find it. Did you fullfill my request there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468628/android-send-data-to-website-and-receive-reply?noredirect=1#comment50911195_31468628

Comment: Well you did not fullfill my request there. You did not react on the wrong parameter names i pointed out. Instead you started a new post. You are not even reacting now that i come back to you. Why? Quide rude to say nothing.

Comment: I just add the form, sorry I am new

Comment: Ok. But then react also on that i said they were different. In this new post you name them  `(emision,cupon,algoritmo)`. But that still is not correct. Please have a better look. Look at the id's.

Comment: Sorry, not at tne id's but at the names.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the complete endpoint of the service which is getting called after pressing the controla button. I checked the url given by you. It uses the ajax to contact the webservice and get the data.

Comment: Thanks.I cant find a tutorial. How I need to google it? ajax webservice android?

Answer (score 1):

Hello i am not sure but may be there is a issue in this line

```
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

**Should be like...**

```
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
```

Please check it and reply if you are still getting this issue.

also check all the parameters KeyName
Thanks!